# Lg g3 open an application?

Tags: applications, default-applications, google-apps, lg-g3, app-drawer

I just go a new lg g3 today, and I noticed a pop-up saying to look at an app which lists all of the features. Now, I was in the app, but when I edited the app, the one time pop-up disappeared, and I want to open it up again.

[image]

I have tried searching in 'my apps' in play store, but it's not there. I manager to find it in 'application manager'

[image]

I want to reopen this app, and have been trying for a few hours now. Please help.

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

Smart Tips is part of Smart Bulletin - the permanent screen to the left of the other home screens on the default LG launcher.

It can be turned on/off in home screen settings, accessed either via the app drawer (three dots at the top right) or the settings app. 
[image: Accessing Smart Bulletin settings]

When you turn on Smart Bulletin, Smart Tips is automatically enabled. Occasionally it will notify you of new tips that are available.